# Find the exact match and use pre and post

Tags: perl

Find the exact pair of `equation (begin and end)` and change this into `align (begin and end)` where the `<check>` tags were found.

#### My data

```
my $str = '
\begin{equation}
v_{i}(t)=M\xi_{l}^{-1}(\Vert z^{0}\Vert_{\infty}+\varepsilon)\xi_{i}e^{\gamma t},\quad t\geq 0.\label{eq:2.3}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
v_{\kappa}(q_{\kappa j}t)=M\xi_{l}^{-1}(\Vert z^{0}\Vert_{\infty}+\varepsilon)\xi_{\kappa}e^{\gamma q_{\kappa j}t}= v_{\kappa}(t)e^{-\gamma (1-q_{\kappa j})t}\leq v_{\kappa}(t).\label{eq:2.4}
<check>
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
|z_{i}(0)|\lt\xi_{l}^{-1}(\Vert z^{0}\Vert_{\infty}+\varepsilon)\xi_{i} \leq M\xi_{l}^{-1}(\Vert z^{0}\Vert_{\infty}+\varepsilon)\xi_{i}= v_{i}(0), i\in J.\label{eq:2.5}
<check>
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
|z_{i}(t) | \lt v_{i}(t)\quad \mbox{for all } t \in (0, T],\  i\in J.\label{eq:2.6}
\end{equation}';
```

#### My code

```
while( $str =~ m/\\begin\{((?:[^{}]*)\*?)\}((?:(?!\\end\{\1\}).)*)<check>((?:(?!\\end\{\1\}).)*)\\end\{\1\}/sgi ) { 
    print "Found: $&\n";
}
```

My way of checking is finding `\begin{}` to `\end{}`, finding the `<check>` element,
and then changing the `equation` to `align`. Here if equations are more than 1000 then the tool is consuming too much time to check each one. Hence need to check another way.

Can I do it this way?

- Find the `<check>` element directly
- Go to `\begin{equation}` before it
- Change that into `\begin{align}`
- Find the closing `\end{equation}`
- Change that into `\end{align} ($' post check)`

I thought it possible.

Comment: Please mentioned reasons for downvote might be improve my way of asking the question

Comment: I don't know why exactly it was downvoted, but I can see one big flaw: you don't say anything about your code -- what is wrong with it (what does it do, why does it not work?), nor how you meant to solve the problem with it (what did you think it would do?).  I would have to carefully pick through a long regex and guess what you wanted with it and what it does.  Another minor point: breaking very long lines would help readibility a lot.  The "data" you may have to leave sometimes (so not to introduce newlines), but there is no reason to leave your code in one long string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the easiest is to slurp the whole file in and find the whole equations

```
perl -0777 -wpe'
    s[ \\begin{equation} (.*? <check> .*?) \\end{equation} ]
     [ \\begin{align} $1 \\end{align} ]gsx
' file.tex  > changed_file.tex
```

When the match fails no substitution is done so there is no need to first find matches. With `-p` the current "line" (`$_`, the whole file here) is printed, changed or not, so we process the whole file.

The `.*?` matches up to the first `<check>` and then the second `.*?` matches from after it to the first `\end{equation}`. There may be more `<check>` tags there but that doesn't concern us since they need not be identified. As long as there is any one inside the equation the substitution goes.

A `Latex/Tex` document is extremely unlikely to be too large to process at once.

---

An alternative would be to keep markers on elements of interest, and once a `<check>` tag is detected change them. You can populate a separate array with file's lines as you read, to avoid `seek`-ing back and forth in the file, and change its elements. At the end output that array as the processed file.